# Is there sound diffraction grating?

Tags: optics, waves, acoustics, interference, diffraction

Sound is also a wave phenomenon. Therefore, is there any counterpart of the usual optical grating for sound?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question). The answer is easily found by [the obvious Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sound%20diffraction%20grating).